# Recent activity page in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

We have a big system with hundreds of models (Users, Employees, Payments, Tasks, Projects, and so on).

We would like to implement a main page for our system that displays the latest activity (a Facebook-like page). This main page would be very simple and display something like:

Project #123 modified by Frank Smith (1 hour ago).

Task #129 created by John Cook (1 day ago).

etc.

Each of these will link to the modified model. Is there an "easy" way to implement this without having to spread code through all our system?

I'm sure Laravel has something that would make implementing this very simple. But can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Laravel is an MVC framework and includes an ORM. These should be enough to make an implementation of such a requirement "easy". Is there any specific thing that is not easy to implement or you're stuck in?

Comment: Is there anything currently in place for you to be able to see who made a change and if so what is it?

Answer (score 2):

Define a common interface for the models that you care about to make sure you can pull the id, name, or any other information from all the models.  (Edit: You probably don't need the model to define the user and timestamp since that can be pulled from the current timestamp and the current auth user).

Define an event listener for 'eloquent.saved' that checks if the model implements that interface and creates the feed "post" with that information.

Comment: thanks. I like your proposal. Would you help me, how would I define such an event listener and how would I know if it implements the interface?

Comment: It's kind of a generic strategy, so you could explicitly listen for 'eloquent.saved'  and you can receive the model in your listener/callback,  you could define an observer on the Model class like George outlines below, you could define a trait with a static boot method, but the real power is using the common interface.   The interface can be checked with `if ($model instanceof Interface)`

Answer (score 1):

I would personally go down the route of Laravel Model Observers. You can then save the events you would like to a table in the database and use that for your main page. You can read more about Model observers here - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers

Comment: George, I've just checked the link. It sounds like a good answer. However, we would have to write an observer for each Model. If there's not better choice I suppose we can do that. But we were thinking some option that would be more "automatic" for all models. Like an observer for the parent class.

Comment: Eloquent models just extend a parent model class. You could instead use `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` and observe that rather than your specific model. That way that one model observer will observe all events from all models.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally used it yet (will do very soon) but i thought this library might suit your needs: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog

I hope it works for your case